# What does the extension method do in c# and why do you need it?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am recently learning about c# and read that the extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. What are some examples to clarify this?

Comment: Exactly what part of the Microsoft documentation wasn't clear: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?  It's worth noting that Extension Methods are .aren't limited to C#: you can call also use them with VB.Net.

Comment: It's worth noting that extension methods only appear like members because you can call them in the same way, which is convenient. They were added with LINQ so you could chain extension method calls rather than nest them. They are still external to the type though, so they call still only access public members, where actual member methods can access private members too.

Answer (score 5):

Extension Methods allow an existing type to be extended with new methods without changing the definition of the original. It allows you to add functionality to a type that you may not be able to inherit (because it's `sealed`) or you don't have the source code.

Here is an example. We will add an `Age()` method to `DateTime`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime birthdate = new DateTime(1980, 10, 7);

        Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + DateTime.Now.Age(birthdate));
    }   
}


public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Age(this DateTime date, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        int birthYear = birthDate.Year;
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

        return currentYear - birthYear - 1;
    }
}
```

You can see from the example that we added a new `Age()` method to C#'s `DateTime` type. Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: It's also useful for adding methods to things that can't normally define methods, like interfaces, enums, etc. (and yes, I know C# now has default interface methods but they behave differently from extension methods on interfaces).

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods are special static methods in a static class which enables us to add new methods to built-in types and custom types without creating new derived type. Which provides a user defined custom functionality just like built-in methods have. For Example, String has ToLower(), ToUpper() methods.
In same way we can create our own method.

Let's check following example, we have created Remove() method which removes any given character/string from original string.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string sample1 = "This, is a, sample string";

        Console.WriteLine("output string : " + sample1.Remove(","));
    }   
}


public static class SampleExtensions
{
    public static string Remove(this string str1, string InputStr)
    {       
        return str1.Replace(InputStr,"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

An extension method in C# allows you to add functionality to an existing class or interface without modifying the class or interface itself. It is a static method that is defined in a static class and is called as if it were an instance method of the extended class or interface.

The main benefits of using extension methods are

**Extending functionality**: Extension methods allow you to add new functionality to existing classes or interfaces without modifying them. This can be useful when you want to add a new feature to a class that you don't have access to modify, such as a third-party library.

**Code re usability:** Extension methods can be reused across different projects and classes, which can save you time and effort in writing similar code.

**Readability:** Extension methods can make your code more readable and concise by encapsulating complex logic into a single method call.

Here is an example of an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Reverse(this string str)
    {
        char[] charArray = str.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
}
```

In this example, we have defined an extension method called Reverse for the string class. The method takes a string as an input and returns the reverse of the string.

To use this extension method in your code, you simply need to call it as if it were an instance method of the string class, like this:

```
string originalString = "Hello, world!";
string reversedString = originalString.Reverse();
```

In this example, the Reverse method is called on the originalString object, which is an instance of the string class. The method returns a new string, which is assigned to the reversedString variable.

Overall, extension methods can be a powerful tool for extending and customizing the behavior of your code without modifying existing classes or creating new subclasses, and they can help make your code more readable and reusable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).